# Maxima of $Tr(X^TAX)/Tr(X^TBX)$ if $A,B$ are p.s.d?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-optimization

What is the maxima of $g(X) = Tr(X^TAX)/Tr(X^TBX)$ if $A,B$ are square, symmetric and positive semi-definite? All matrices are real-valued and X is a rectangular matrix. Also there is a constraint that $Tr(X^TC)=\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a non-zero scalar. Is it trivial based on the eigen-vectors of $A$ and $B$, or is there more to it?

Comment: Notice that $X^T B X$ might be $0$...

Comment: oops. my bad, I edited and added an appropriate constraint that I have that does not let $X$ become a matrix of all zero's.

Comment: I don't get your constraint. You assumed that $B$ is semi-definite, thus $B$ might have a nontrivial null space. (Which might intersect with the null space of $C^T$). Just assume $B$ be definite and $X\ne 0$. Then, it should be right.

Comment: Ok, but in my case I have a $B$ that is definitely p.s.d........  As long as I can maximize $g(X)$ and also ensure $X\neq 0$ via additional constraints as required...am okay. unfortunately $B$ is p.s.d for sure...

Comment: Wait...I can actually use https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/nearPD.html to convert my p.s.d matrix B into a p.d matrix by finding the nearest PD matrix to it and approximate it with it using that link. In that case I can take your suggestion of p.d B .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For positive definite $B$ we have 
$$ \max_{X\ne 0} \frac{tr(X^T A X)}{tr(X^T B X)} = \max_{tr(Y^T Y) = 1} tr(Y^T B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} Y) = \lambda_{max}(B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}). $$

Comment: Notably, this coincides with $\lambda_{max}(AB^{-1})$

Comment: how do you obtain the first equality?

Comment: @LinAlg notice that $tr(X^T B X) > 0$. So by rescaling you can assume $tr(X^T B X)=1$. Now, substitute by $Y = B^{1/2}X$.